# Can't connect to Apache Ignite Cluster on AWS EC2 - Ignite server rejects clients

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ignite

I have problems with connecting to my Ignite cluster. I have 2 nodes on AWS EC2 and I use AWS S3 based discovery. Ignites nodes start without errors and I see how new objects appear at S3 bucket after launching Ignite. 
In AWS Securuty groups I opened all TCP ports so that it is expected that anyone can connect to the cluster.

But I get `org.apache.ignite.client.ClientConnectionException: Ignite cluster is unavailable` exception when I try to connect from my computer (I try to run simple JUnit tests from IDE).

I used the following configuration:

```
    <property name="addressResolver">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BasicAddressResolver">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="EC2 internal IP" value="EC2 public ip"/>
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.s3.TcpDiscoveryS3IpFinder">
                    <property name="awsCredentials" ref="reference to another bean with aws creds"/>
                    <property name="bucketName" value="MY_BUCKET_NAME"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

The problem here is that server rejects any attempts to connect, because when I start Ignite client (not Thin client) I see at logs the following picture:
[image]

As you can see, the number of clients become equal to 0 then 1, 0 and 1 and etc.
So I suppose, clients can reach the cluster, but why are they being rejected?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem. It seems there is a rule: If you use AWS S3 based discovery in your Ignite cluster, your Ignite client nodes should use the same approach as well. It wasn't obvious for me.

According to the [official documentation](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/amazon-aws#amazon-s3-based-discovery):

```
TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials("yourAccessKey", "yourSecreteKey");

TcpDiscoveryS3IpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryS3IpFinder();
ipFinder.setAwsCredentials(creds);
ipFinder.setBucketName("yourBucketName");
```